# Should I purchase ART HeadAmp 6 PRO Headphone Amp with 6 Free Headphones for $199?

Tags: headphones

I need a headphone amp for my basement studio. I'm in two metal bands and I'm trying to move to electronic drums and headphones for all our instruments.

I saw this amp on both Guitar Center and Musician's Friend:

http://pro-audio.musiciansfriend.com/product/ART-HeadAmp-6-PRO-Headphone-Amp-with-6-Free-Headphones?sku=485792

It's priced the same ($199) with free shipping from both.

The reviews seem good, but does anyone have any experience with this product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have their older [HeadAmp four-output box](http://www.artproaudio.com/products.asp?type=91&cat=14&id=62). It's been a solid little box. Quiet with preamps that have a ton of gain so you can drive loud signals over long cable runs. I think I paid ~CAD$75 maybe 8 years ago now. Didn't come with any cans. It's one of those little boxes I have in the home studio that I don't think about, use all the time, and if it was gone I'd miss it very much.

I doubt the cans it's coming with are of great quality but, to me, that price seems pretty darn good.

Comment: That's what I was hoping for. Thanks, @Ian!